# jQuery plugin to "see more" text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that does this:

Original:

> i am such a nice guy that just needs to become a lot more concise.... help me... help me...

Needed:

> i am such a nice guy that... [see more]

Requirements:

- cut by word, not character length
- very light and simple, no mess needed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just hacked [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/hgxbf/) together.

You can use it by calling `trunc` on all of the elements you want to have a see more label on. You pass it an argument of the maximum number of words in the un-expanded text.

Example:

```
// truncate all text in elements with class "truncateme" to be 10 words or less
// (until you click the "see more" link)
$(".truncateme").trunc(10);
```

Comment: Very nice tip. Is there any way to animate the effect? Something like slideDown()?

Comment: @Fabio: You could probably achieve that one way or another, but there's no dead-simple way to do that. You could have it `slideUp`, expand/collapse the text, and then `slideDown`. Not as seamless as just sliding in the previously-truncated text, but it's still a little animation if you feel obligated to throw some in.

Answer (score 1):

If CSS3 is an option for you, you can use the `text-overflow` property.

If not, [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis) is a list of jQuery plugins that do what you are looking for

Comment: good to know css3 has that! unfortunately, it is not an option (for now)  ;)